# Cannot access [file] because it is being used by another process. The file is locked by: "Windows PowerShell ISE"

Tags: powershell

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to code a cmdlet. I made a class derived from a cmdlet, and wrote a psd1 file called manifest.psd1.

However, when I change some code and rebuild the project to the release directory, vs tells me like

> 1>C:\Tools\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4106,5): warning MSB3026: Could not copy "obj\Release\MyPowerShellCS.dll" to "bin\Release\MyPowerShellCS.dll". Beginning retry 10 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'bin\Release\MyPowerShellCS.dll' because it is being used by another process. The file is locked by: "Windows PowerShell ISE (9356)"

It looks like `MyPowerShellCS.dll` has been locked by PowerShell ISE?

I've tried removing this module, but doesn't work.How can I unlock it via script?

Comment: Closing PowerShell ISE should do the trick.

Comment: *via script*: `ise; exit`

Comment: @PetSerAl , thx for your answer. I'm just wandering if there is other solution than closing powershell ise.

Comment: .NET have its own limitation. For example: you can not unload single assembly, you need to unload whole `AppDomain`. But PowerShell ISE do not create separate `AppDomain`s, so you are out of luck here.